# nagios - Web interface: authentication through kerberos OK, what about authorization on cgi.cfg?

Tags: nagios, openldap, kerberos

I have successfully installed nagios, and it provides authentication through apache2 which contacts a kerberos authentication server to authenticate users.

Now, users are authenticated, but they don't have any authorization as authorization is configured on `cgi.cfg` and I don't want to configure all my users one by one manually, or give all rights to each authenticated user.

I would like to know if groups can be set on the `cgi.cfg` file (such as nagios_reader, with right to watch web interface, host and services status, and nagios_writer, with the ability to run external commands) instead of on the user, and if these groups can be extracted from  LDAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if groups can be set on cgi.cfg file

I'm afraid that the answer is no. Nagios hasn't supported this feature yet. The value of [`authorized_`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html) options must be a comma-delimited list of names of authenticated users. But if, as you said, *"these groups can be extracted from a LDAP"*, so you can add every members in a group with a little shell script.

Nagios has the [`authorized_for_read_only`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html#authorized_for_read_only) option to configure a list of usernames that have read-only rights in the CGIs. Assuming that the `nagios_reader.ldif` contains:

```
# nagios_reader, it, domain.com
dn: cn=nagios_reader,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
cn: nagios_reader
member: cn=foo,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
member: cn=bar,ou=it,dc=domain,dc=com
objectClass: groupOfNames
objectClass: top
```

You can configure all the members of this group as a value of `authorized_for_read_only` variable by using:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -W -D "cn=manager,dc=domain,dc=com" "cn=nagios_reader" | \
    awk -F"=|," '/member: / { print $2 }' | \
    while read u; do sed -i "/^authorized_for_read_only/s/$/,$u/" cgi.cfg; done
```

Comment: Ok quanta thanks for your answer I have been looking around these last few days and found nothing simpler than the solution you propose. I maybe should have a closer look at shinken, base on Nagios, which may propose another authentication method to access its web interface.

Comment: @philippe, I'd not heard of Shinken.  Looks pretty nice.  If you're looking into nagios front-ends, be sure to check out [Opsview](http://opsview.com) as well.  I've been digging into that lately.  It has a fairly granular permissions setup.  There is a free version.