# Nagios - Is it possible to create "view only" users and let them view only specific services/servers?

Tags: nagios

We have Nagios Core 3.2.1 installed and my current task is to allow non-admin users access to the Nagios UI.
Is that even possible? or would i need to install some add-on?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/421160/59925

Comment: Sure is and it's all covered by the documentation. I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible to create “view only” users?

Sure, you can do it by using the [`authorized_for_read_only`](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configcgi.html#authorized_for_read_only) variable:

**`/usr/local/nagios/etc/cgi.cfg`**

```
# A comma-delimited list of usernames that have read-only rights in
# the CGIs. This will block any service or host commands normally shown
# on the extinfo CGI pages. It will also block comments from being shown
# to read-only users.

authorized_for_read_only=anonymous
```

> and let them view only specific services/servers?

Create a [contact definition](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectdefinitions.html#contact) with the same `contact_name`:

**`/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/contacts.cfg`**

```
define contact{
        contact_name                    anonymous
        use                             generic-contact
        alias                           No Name
        service_notifications_enabled   1
        host_notifications_enabled      1
        service_notification_period     24x7
        host_notification_period        24x7
        service_notification_options    c,w,r
        host_notification_options       d,u,r
        email                           anonymous@domain.com
        }
```

*(that's called a [authenticated contact](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/cgiauth.html))*

then make him is the contact of the hosts/services which you want to allow to view:

```
define host{
        use                     linux-server
        host_name               localhost
        address                 127.0.0.1
        contacts                anonymous
        contact_groups          admin
        }
```

Comment: I've edited the cgi.cfg and the contacts.cfg files but when i add the contacts contact_name in the services file i'm getting an error while trying to restart nagios service.

Comment: How can we help without seeing the error.

Comment: that's the error i received: Running configuration check... FAILED!  Restart aborted.  Check your Nagios configuration.

Comment: `nagios -v /path/to/the/nagios.cfg`?

Comment: That's the error: Error: Contact 'it' specified in service 'MS Terminal server' for host 'xp-ams-2' is not defined anywhere!
even though i've added the user to the cgi.cfg and contacts.cfg..
define contact{
        contact_name                    it
        alias                           IT
        host_notification_period        24x7
        service_notification_period     24x7
        host_notification_options       d,r
        service_notification_options    w,u,c,r
        host_notification_commands      host-notify-by-email
        service_notification_commands   notify-by-email

Comment: there's also the email email@domain.com line

Comment: Append it to your original question to keep formatting instead of posting here as a comment.

Comment: while running the verification of Nagios configuration file i saw that it's checking different files than the default ones, so i've edited them and achieved my goal. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, Simply create a user without any special privs.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have tried changing the `authorized_for_read_only` property as well. but in order to view the services and hosts following configuration changes needed to be done as well.  After that restart the apache server.

```
authorized_for_all_services=nagiosadmin,--your user--
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagiosadmin,--your user--
```